# Table view button index cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have one table view in that cell is custom. I am adding two button on each cell of table view. when I click on first button at same time second button from same cell is changing its image. for that I have methods as `editQuantity` and `Cancelorder`. using @sel. I am getting an issue that when i click on first button  insted of changing same cell another button its changing another cells button also when I scroll table view its losses all selected button

```
Here Is My Code--

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{

simpleTableIdentifier = @"MenuNameCell";
    MenuNameCell *cell = (MenuNameCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
   if (cell== nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MenuNameCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"---------new cell agin");   
    }
       else
    {
        NSArray *arrayView = [cell.contentView subviews];
        for (UIView *vTemp in arrayView)
        {
            [vTemp removeFromSuperview];
        }

        NSLog(@"---No New Cell hiiii");

        // Setting Tag To UIButton
        _checkButton = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row];
        _cancelButton = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:indexPath.row];
    }
    // Creating Label Menu Name
    _nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(8, 11, 82, 21)];
    _nameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    _nameLabel.text =  [_hotel._orderedMenus objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    // Creating Label Menu Cost
    _amountMenu   = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(167, 13, 44, 21)];
    _amountMenu.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    _amountMenu.text  = [[_hotel._menuPrices objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringValue];

    // Creating Text Field For Order Quantity
    _textFieldQuantity = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(125,14,42,21)];
    _textFieldQuantity.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    _textFieldQuantity.text = [[_hotel._selectedQuantity objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] stringValue];

    // Creating Button For Check Order
    _checkButton  = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [_checkButton setFrame:CGRectMake(232, 13, 25, 28)];
    [_checkButton setTag:indexPath.row];
    _checkButton.titleLabel.tag = indexPath.row;
    [_checkButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"edit.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_checkButton addTarget:self action:@selector(editQuantity:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    // Creating Button For CANCEL Order
    _cancelButton  = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [_cancelButton setFrame:CGRectMake(265, 13, 25, 28)];
    [_cancelButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"cancel.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [_cancelButton setTag:indexPath.row];
    _cancelButton.titleLabel.tag = indexPath.row;
    [_cancelButton addTarget:self  action:@selector(cancelOreder:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    // Adding All To Content View
    [cell.contentView addSubview:_nameLabel];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:_amountMenu];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:_textFieldQuantity];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:_checkButton];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:_cancelButton];


    //objc_setAssociatedObject(_checkButton, iindex, indexPath,OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN );

    return cell;
  }


-(void)editQuantity:(id)sender{

    button = (UIButton *)sender;
    row = button.tag;
    col = button.titleLabel.tag;
    NSLog(@"Check Button index is %d",row);
    NSLog(@"cehck title is %d",col);
    _textFieldQuantity.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"edit_over.png"];
    [_checkButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIImage *buttonImageCancel = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check.png"];
    [_cancelButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImageCancel forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    _cancelButton.tag =  0;

} 

-(void)cancelOreder:(id)sender{

    button = (UIButton *)sender;
    row = button.tag;
    NSLog(@"The Row Selected iS At Cancel Order ISSSS----%d", row);
    if (_cancelButton.tag ==  0){
        _textFieldQuantity.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        UIImage *buttonImageCancel = [UIImage imageNamed:@"check_over.png"];
        [_cancelButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImageCancel  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        UIImage *buttonImageCancel1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cancel.png"];
        [_cancelButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImageCancel1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"edit.png"];
        [_checkButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        _cancelButton.tag = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert =  [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"iHomeDelivery" message:@"Do You Want To Cancel the Order" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }

}
```

Comment: Not going to read all that, please trim your code down to only what's necessary for your question.

Comment: i have edited my code pls suggest ans

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the default tag value for any control is set to `0` and you have used the `_cancelButton.tag =  0;`. Just change the value to `10` and then `_cancelButton.tag = 1;` change `1` to `11`.

This will solve your problem :)

Comment: in your `-(void)editQuantity:(id)sender` and `-(void)cancelOreder:(id)sender` methods change the tag values. `NEVER USE 0` when ever you want to use it in the conditional statements.

Answer (score 0):

As I see _checkButton, _nameLabel, _amountMenu, _textFieldQuantity & _cancelButton all are instance variable of your view controller class.

In cellForRowAtIndexPath: as you are assigning new objects to all these, they will refere to objects of last cell displayed. Means all these will point to components from last cell.
Hence changing background images for _checkButton & _cancelButton will affect for buttons in last cell.

Also in cellForRowAtIndexPath: while creating these buttons, you are setting background image for them, hence after scrolling your button images are getting changed. Remember cellForRowAtIndexPath: gets called for a row each time that row becomes visible after getting hidden while scrolling.

You need to maintain state of buttons in separate array, so that you can reset state for buttons in cellForRowAtIndexPath: after dequeuing.

Comment: your explanation is correct but how to maintain button statecan you give me sample code

Comment: I don't have any with me now. I will try to make one for you when I will get time.